# Which log level should be used to log developer specific logs

Tags: java, slf4j

Which log level should be used, is it `org.slf4j.logger.Logger.trace or debug` for logging the low level developer logs?

Comment: This is highly subjective and basically you need to establish some convention in your team. I once tried to define some rules: http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2010/05/clean-code-clean-logs-logging-levels.html - but it is really up to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good list describing the log levels:

- **Debug**
  This is the most verbose logging level (maximum volume setting). I usually consider Debug to be out-of-bounds for a production system and used it only for development and testing. I prefer to aim to get my logging levels just right so I have just enough information and endeavour to log this at the Information level or above.
- **Information**
  The Information level is typically used to output information that is useful to the running and management of your system. Information would also be the level used to log Entry and Exit points in key areas of your application. However, you may choose to add more entry and exit points at Debug level for more granularity during development and testing.
- **Warning**
  Warning is often used for handled 'exceptions' or other important log events. For example, if your application requires a configuration setting but has a default in case the setting is missing, then the Warning level should be used to log the missing configuration setting.
- **Error**
  Error is used to log all unhandled exceptions. This is typically logged inside a catch block at the boundary of your application.
- **Fatal**
  Fatal is reserved for special exceptions/conditions where it is imperative that you can quickly pick out these events. I normally wouldn't expect Fatal to be used early in an application's development. It's usually only with experience I can identify situations worthy of the FATAL moniker experience do specific events become worth of promotion to Fatal. After all, an error's an error.

From http://thejoyofcode.com/Logging_Levels_and_how_to_use_them.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by *developer* logs. If you mean debugging information, obviously `DEBUG` should be used.

People tend to use `TRACE` for extremely fine grained logs such as method entry, method exit etc which would litter the log files if enabled.

This method might give you an example.

```
public String fetchMessage(long id) {
    logger.entry(id);

    logger.debug("Retrieving message from database");

    String message = this.messageService.fetchMessageById(id);

    logger.exit(message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Logs are very important for the debugging and sometimes troubleshooting. Its good to log all the required information. However, excessive logging may also hamper performance e.g. writing long XML messages or something similar.

That's why there are different levels available for logging. Need to choose appropriate level for kind of information.

e.g have error level of logs in the catch block.

```
catch (Exception e) {
   log.error("Exception... information.");
}
```

some obvious information required all the time.
    log.info("log info"); //Basic information- turned on always

debug level information
    log.debug("debug values..."); //Can turn on this level as and when required.

It will save from excessive logging.

Thumb rule:- never log sensitive information in logs.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your local workflow and how you do things.

Our rule of thumb is that INFO is always on, DEBUG is logged in production when needed for forensic analysis, but that TRACE isn't logged outside the developers machine.

This mean that if you need to have information available to you to investigate, log it at debug.  If not, log it at trace.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are no "developper log" and "user log". 
Each package should contain a little independant API with **its own concepts and layers**.

What you call the "developper log" is probably a sub part of the "Kernel" of you application and what you would call the "user log" would be the "Command line" or "UI" part.

Each package should be considered independently with its own Object model and business rules. In this universe you usually have a "**Public**" part on the top layer which handles the basic steps of the use cases. You also have a "**Protected**" part for extending the functionnalities and a "**Private**" part for your internal needs.
This **layers** could be stored in different **java package**s in a hierarchical way.
Your logging practice should probably be based on this layers scheme.

The good practice is to use an API such as **java.logging** or **log4j**... wich allows you to log on a package name basis.

**INFO** should be basic high level step, meaning what happens in the **public** method of the **top layer** of your package.

**DEBUG** should be a more finer grain that still does not affect the performances.

**TRACE** should be use for a very verbose log that could result in a performance issue. Remember to always wrap the call to trace() within a if(level==TRACE) so you don't perform some useless tasks of building a message... etc.

**WARN** when an Exception could be handled.

**ERR** when an Exception was not handled but did not result in shutting down the main Thread.

**FATAL** when I had to terminate the whole process.

Good luck!

Renaud